# Check location access granted globally

Tags: react-native

I want to check whether the location is active throughout the app. I'm currently using the following custom hook placed in the parent component of my navigation container.

But I don't get the location model appearing.

Following is the code that appear in the component.

```
const [locationAccessGranted, currentLocation] = useLocation();
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    !locationAccessGranted ? setVisible(true) : setVisible(false);
}, [locationAccessGranted]);

return (
    <>
        <RootNavigation />
        <Modal visible={visible}>
            <Text>Please Enable location</Text>
        </Modal>
    </>
)
```

My hooks code (useLocation)

```
function useLocation() {
    const [locationAccessGranted, setLocationAccessGranted] = useState(null);
    const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState({
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const grantLocationAccess = async () => {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    'title': 'App Location Permission',
                    'message': 'App needs access to your location ',
                });
            setLocationAccessGranted(granted);
            if (granted) {
                Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                    setCurrentLocation({ latitude: latitude.toString(), longitude: longitude.toString() });
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error.code, error.message);
                },
                    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
                );
            }
        };
        grantLocationAccess();
    }, []);

    return [locationAccessGranted, currentLocation];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the permission in the androidmanifest.xml for Android and in the info.plist for IOS?

Comment: I have added the permission.